# Show a loading screen at launch in App Delegate

Tags: ios, loading, startup, wait

I'm building an app where it needs to load information from an XML file at startup.

I'm calling the fetching method in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the `AppDelegate` class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   [self fetch];    
   return true;
}
```

But I would like to show an image when the app lunches and I want it to disappear when the fetch method finishes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to remove your `Default.png`, create an UIViewController with a UIImageView with that Default.png image, load the XML on that viewContoller and then after loading move away from that viewController

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a blog](http://gigaom.com/2010/04/20/iphone-dev-sessions-making-a-splash-screen/) which does the same. It loads an image on window performs the action and then removes it.

You can also create a SplashViewContrller make it first view controller with you image, load you xaml and when loading is done present you new controller with animation `NO`

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily use a storyboard to have an initial view controller for loading with an indicator view, and then trigger the next view controller with a segue once loading is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a view controller, so called `LoadingViewController` as the root controller to be loaded after the `appdelegate`, make it conform to `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol delegate or whatever other XML parser you are using. In the method which get called when parsing is starting, set the loading image, then dismiss it on the method which get called when the parsing is finished.

For instance, `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol has the following two methods:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
//Show loading image
}
```

and

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
//Parsing document has finished, dismiss loading image
}
```

***PS:*** I don't know which protocol or third party library you are using to parse XML on your project, but I assume they all have handlers for start/end parsing which you should rely on to respectively show/dismiss loading image.